# Calling an async method from the database seed method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, initializer

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and would like to know how to call an `async` method from the `seed` method when a database is created.

Here is my code:

```
public class ApplicationDbInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext> 
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context) {            
        SetupAdminAndSampleObjectsDatabase();
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Currently, when calling the `SetupAdminAndSampleObjectsDatabase` method, I am getting the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException: A second operation started on this
>   context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use
>   'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed
>   before calling another method on this context. Any instance members
>   are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Here is the method definition:

```
public async Task SetupAdminAndSampleObjectsDatabase()
```

I am adding multiple objects in this method.

Am I correct in saying that the above error will be resolved if the `SetupAdminAndSampleObjectsDatabase` method is called with the `await` keyword?

So, in summary, how can I call an `async` method from the database `seed` method? Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

1) Make the Seed method async, and use await

```
protected override async void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context) {            
        await SetupAdminAndSampleObjectsDatabase();
        base.Seed(context);
    }
```

2) Use .WaitAndUnwrapException() on the async method

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context) {            
        SetupAdminAndSampleObjectsDatabase().WaitAndUnwrapException();
        base.Seed(context);
    }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware that I could add the async keyword to the override method.

Comment: Just a side note, if you use option 1, you will need to change the return type of `SetupAdminAndSampleObjectsDatabase()` to `Task` if it was originally `void` or `Task<T>` for whatever the original return type `T` was in order to be able to await it.

Comment: I wouldn't be too optimistic that I can get away with option 1. In that case, the caller would not await the created Task and you might end up with an error similar to this: "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending". MSDN sates that async void is only possible "to make asynchronous event handlers possible".